# C# - Убрать заголовок из GroupBox, включая пробельные символы

Tags: c#, wpf

В WPF элементе `GroupBox` мне нужно убрать пустое пространство там, где должна находится надпись.

Если установить свойство равным пустой строке

```
Header = ""
```

то все равно остается пустое место. Как его убрать?

Или может есть другой контрол для объединения элементов?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поместить два `GroupBox` в `Grid`, перевернув один из них по горизонтали.

```
<Grid>        
    <GroupBox Name="mainGroupBox"> 

    </GroupBox>
    <GroupBox  Focusable="False" Panel.ZIndex="-1" 
       Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=mainGroupBox}" 
       Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=mainGroupBox}" 
       IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled, ElementName=mainGroupBox}"
       RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <GroupBox.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
        </GroupBox.RenderTransform>
    </GroupBox>
</Grid>
```

Идея взята с [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2111401/6936696).

> Или может есть другой контрол для объединения элементов?

Используйте `Border`:

```
<Border BorderBrush="Gray" 
        BorderThickness="1" 
        CornerRadius="5"
        Padding="2" Margin="2">
    <TextBlock Text="text"/>
</Border>
```